# How do I specify a default value for an active record enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following ActiveRecord model with an `enum` column:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:normal, :sales, :admin]
end
```

How do I set the default value for the `role` column **before** saving to the database.

For example:

```
user = User.new
puts user.role # Should print 'normal'
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do before saving to the db? Can this be done during saving of the record to db?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:normal, :sales, :admin]

  after_initialize do
    if self.new_record?
      self.role ||= :normal
    end
  end
end
```

or if you prefer

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:normal, :sales, :admin]

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  private

  def set_defaults
    if self.new_record?
      self.role ||= :normal
    end
  end
end
```

Note that we use ||= to prevent the after_initialize clobbering anything passed in during initialization with User.new(some_params)

Comment: What happens when the object is initialized with a role: `User.new(role: 'sales')` ?

Comment: Dammit you're right. The after_initialize would stomp the parameter... so I need a ||= to not overwrite it. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it as :default to 'normal' in a migration file.

little good examples: [LINK](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:normal, :sales, :admin]

  #before_save {self.role ||= 'normal'}
  # or
  #before_create {self.role = 'normal'}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this callback, before_save

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     before_save :default_values

        def default_values
          self.role ||= "normal"
        end
end
```

Comment: With your code `user = User.new; user.role` will return `nil`.

Comment: Why don't you try to add the default value throught migration to the existing column.

Comment: Defaults set in the database only apply **after** a model is saved.